# why the footer not aligned here?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and i tried to create a simple login form with table. But the footer content is not aligned?

How to align this footer without using css?

I need to create this form without the use of footer tag?

So can any one explain how to do the alignment?

```
<body>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td> <h2>Login form</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center">
                <form name="new" action=""  onsubmit="">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>User name:<p></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Password:<p></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Go!"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>About</p></td>
        <td><p>Contact</p></td>
        <td><p>Press</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do you want to align? Left,right or center?

Comment: Why put a table in a table....

Comment: Why use a table at all?

Comment: It is already _center_ aligned. See [This](http://jsfiddle.net/uCY3A/).

Comment: yeah but that is not properly aligned,i need same distance between all the three <p> tags

Comment: @joe I can understand someone new wanting to use a table but there's no reason for a table in a table, unless he was trying to make baby tables. ;)

Comment: @Ruddy Baby tables are kind of cute.  However, even as a beginner, it should be learned correctly.  It is much more difficult to unlearn the wrong way and learn the right way than to just learn the right way to begin with.  Tables should not be used for layout.  It breaks the Internet.  :D

Comment: @joe Ok, your right... but joe.... think about the baby tables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `colspan=3` to first and second td,

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"> <h2>Login form</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<table align="center">
<form name="new" action=""  onsubmit="">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" ><p>User name:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" ><p>Password:</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Go!"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>About</p></td>
<td><p>Contact</p></td>
<td><p>Press</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/uCQG4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to learn about colspans and rowspans, since you've got 2 cells on the the first and second row and then 3 on the last row, it's forcing the tag to push over.

Research:  in tables

It will solve your problem